# LINQ updating image

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to make simple image updating in LINQ, but everything else except IMAGE is updating, and image stays the same... why is that?
Here's some of my code, can enyone tell me what do I do wrong?

So, I'm using button, to choose photo, (pretty simple) and string path2 is my path

```
 using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";
            dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path2 = dlg.FileName;
                //textBox1.Text = path;
                pictureBox2.ImageLocation = @path2;
                pictureBox2.Refresh();
            }
            dlg.Dispose();
        }
```

and later I'm modyfiy values

```
 selectedprodukt.Nazwa = modyfikuj_nazwa_produktu.Text;
                selectedprodukt.Cena = Convert.ToDecimal(modyfikuj_cena_produktu.Text);
                selectedprodukt.Opis = modyfikuj_opis_produktu.Text;
                selectedprodukt.Image = File.ReadAllBytes(path2);
                selectedprodukt.Producent = p.First();
                db.SaveChanges();
```

everything seems to work fine. First i can see old picture in picturebox, then when I load new picutre it's also good, but then i click save, and the Nazwa, Cena, Opis, Producent is updating as it's supose to, but Image does not

I did debug my project, and path2 has a proper value...

Answer (score 2):

Linq uses it's special type `System.Data.Linq.Binary`.
So you need to modify your update query like this:

```
System.Data.Linq.Binary file_binary = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(File.ReadAllBytes(path2));
selectedprodukt.Nazwa = modyfikuj_nazwa_produktu.Text;
selectedprodukt.Cena = Convert.ToDecimal(modyfikuj_cena_produktu.Text);
selectedprodukt.Opis = modyfikuj_opis_produktu.Text;
selectedprodukt.Image = file_binary;
selectedprodukt.Producent = p.First();
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Ok! I'll be in touch!